# Use AWS CLI to pull in multiple information

Tags: aws-cli

Right now this following code segment will list the 'Name' tag of the resource of any instance that doesn't have a 'Grant' tag.

```
for region in `aws ec2 describe-regions --output text | cut -f3`
do
aws ec2 describe-instances \
   --region $region \
   --output text \
   --query 'Reservations[].Instances[?!not_null(Tags[?Key == `Grant`].Value)] | [].Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value'
done
```

I've tried a few ways to get the Public IP address but I keep getting errors for bad syntax.

Is it possible to pull in the Public IP here?

Comment: What is the error you get? And how are you trying to get the Public IP?

Comment: ,PublicIpAddress after [].Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value

Bad value for --query Reservations[].Instances[?!not_null(Tags[?Key == `Grant`].Value)] | [].Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value, PublicIpAddress: Unexpected token: ,: Parse error at column 95, token "," (COMMA), for expression:
"Reservations[].Instances[?!not_null(Tags[?Key == `Grant`].Value)] | [].Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value, PublicIpAddress"

Comment: What actual output do you want? Can you describe your goal in words? (eg "For every instance that does not have a `Grant` tag, show the Public IP address")

Comment: I want to show the Name tag as well as the Public IP Address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, It is possible to pull the PublicIp address along with the Tags value.
Replace query syntax as below,

```
    --query 'Reservations[].Instances[?!not_null(Tags[?Key == `Grant`].Value)] | [].[PublicIpAddress, Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value]'
```